# BD cadastro de venda

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia.

Estou fazendo um app web de vendas, e quero retornar o ID da venda para inserir na tabela intermediária de venda_produto (vários produtos em 1 venda). Tentei dessa maneira, mas obviamente não consegui:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "narguile");

$number = count($_POST["input_quantidade_venda"]);

$soma_venda = $_POST['soma_venda'];

$data = $_POST['data'];

$hora = $_POST['hora'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO vendas(preco_venda, data, hora) VALUES";
$sql .= "('$soma_venda', '$data', '$hora')";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$id_venda = "SELECT max(id_venda) FROM vendas";

if($number > 0) {

    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) {

        if(trim($_POST["input_quantidade_venda"][$i] != '')) {

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO venda_produto(quantidade, id_venda) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["input_quantidade_venda"][$i])."', '$id_venda')";
            mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);
        }  
    }

    echo "Venda cadastrada!";  
}  

else {

    echo "Não rolou";  
}
?>
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço...

Comment: Já tentou usar a [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php) - Retorna o id gerado automaticamente na última consulta.

**De forma bem resumida**

```
if ($result = $connect->query("INSERT INTO vendas(preco_venda, data, hora) VALUES('$soma_venda', '$data', '$hora');")) {
   $id_venda  = $mysqli->insert_id;
}
```

> A função mysqli_insert_id() retorna o ID gerado por uma consulta em uma tabela com uma coluna com o atributo AUTO_INCREMENT. Se a última consulta não for uma instrução INSERT ou UPDATE ou se a tabela modificada não tiver uma coluna com o atributo AUTO_INCREMENT, essa função retornará zero

Answer (score 0):

Se o ID que utilizar na tabela `vendas` for autoincrementável (propriedade `AUTO_INCREMENT` ativa) pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
// ...
$id_venda = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
// ...
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO venda_produto(quantidade, id_venda) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["input_quantidade_venda"][$i])."', '$id_venda')";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);
// ...
```

Se não for, então poderá ser assim:

```
// ...
$id_venda = "(SELECT MAX(id_venda) FROM vendas)";
// ...
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO venda_produto(quantidade, id_venda) ";
$sql2 .= "SELECT '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["input_quantidade_venda"][$i])."', $id_venda";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);
// ...
```

Existem formas mais "bonitas" de fazer o que pretende, mas aí já depende de si querer melhorar ou não :)

Comment: obg, João...

Estou usando os IDs com AUTO_INCREMENT, então tentei o primeiro código, e apresentou os seguintes erros: 

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in xxx on line 17

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxx on line 17

Tentei o segundo código e funcionou, embora eu não tenha certeza se isso futuramente possa dar algum tipo de conflito...

O SELECT MAX retorna a última linha ou o valor mais alto?

Comment: O `MAX` retorna o valor mais alto. Resposta editada, teste com o novo código!